# Python Ursina neither showing entities nor colliding with them

Tags: python, render, collision, ursina

I have a problem with Python's Ursina 3D Engine module:
It neither shows entities nor the player can collide with them.

Here is my code:

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController as FPC

app = Ursina()

window.borderless = False

ent = Entity("cube",position=(0,-300,0),scale=(100,1,100),color=color.green,collider="mesh")

def update():
    global mesh,player
    # camera.fov,
    print("Player =",list(player.position),"\tEnt =",list(ent.position))

player = FPC()

app.run()
```

The console output of this script:

```
C:\Users\x\Desktop>file.py
package_folder: C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ursina
asset_folder: C:\Users\x\Desktop
:prc(warning): Invalid integer value for ConfigVariable win-size: 819.2000122070312
:prc(warning): Invalid integer value for ConfigVariable win-size: 1024.0
Known pipe types:
  wglGraphicsPipe
(3 aux display modules not yet loaded.)
:prc(warning): changing default value for ConfigVariable paste-emit-keystrokes from '1' to '0'.
1.0
:pnmimage:png(warning): iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
return True
return True
screen resolution: (1280, 1024)
os: Windows
development mode: True
application successfully started
info: changed aspect ratio: 1.25 -> 1.25
Player = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]                        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -0.9801408052444458, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -1.9783879518508911, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -2.163113594055176, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -2.681523561477661, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -3.2287044525146484, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -3.7121353149414062, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
...
Player = [0.0, -289.1733093261719, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -291.11517333984375, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -292.7177734375, 0.0]            Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -294.4815979003906, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -297.0081787109375, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -298.7649230957031, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -301.22381591796875, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -302.47760009765625, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -304.2674865722656, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -306.6351623535156, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -307.9244689941406, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -309.7126770019531, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -311.6873474121094, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -314.0469970703125, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -316.1541442871094, 0.0]         Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
Player = [0.0, -318.04779052734375, 0.0]        Ent = [0.0, -300.0, 0.0]
...
```

The `player` keeps continuing falling, but won't collide with the `ent` entity
and the `ent` entity is not visible, even when I use `EditorCamera()`. When I set the `-300` Y coordinate of `ent` to a another value (e.g. `-100`), it also does not work.

`player` should collide with and land on `ent` and `ent` should be rendered.

What am I doing wrong and/or what is the cause of this error?

Answer (score 0):

You never set the model, which is why you can't see it. Try `model="cube"` instead of just writing `"cube"` (which would set `add_to_scene_entities` to "cube", which doesn't make sense)

If your model is a cube, you should use `collider='box'`, not `collider='mesh'`